# Android CheckBox Custom image not showing properly

Tags: android

In my project I have a CheckBox and I am trying to add a Custom image for checked and unchecked state but the images are not showing properly for xhdpi screen.Kindly help

I am posting the xml and screen shots

### custom_checkbox.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <selector  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_uncheck" />
       <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check" />
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_uncheck" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

### check_box.xml

```
     <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkVibrate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:button="@drawable/checkbox"
        android:text="CheckBox Text"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

[click here for the hdpi image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7EQA.jpg)

[click here for the xhdpi image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFECB.jpg)

Comment: What is the problem here? both images are looking same

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal now check please

Comment: make sure you have corresponding images in the `drawable-hdpi` and `drawable-xhdpi` folders.

Comment: @SMR Ya I have bot images

Comment: plz paste your xml file for checkbox too.

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal please check the xml

Answer (score 1):

You should use your custom xml file for button property

```
 <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkVibrate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
    android:text="CheckBox Text"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

you can create a custom file in this way too if you want to set different image in different focused states.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_checked="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check"
    android:state_focused="false">
</item>
<item android:state_checked="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check"
    android:state_focused="true">
</item>
<item android:state_checked="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_uncheck"
    android:state_focused="false">
</item>
<item android:state_checked="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_uncheck"
    android:state_focused="true">
</item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Not working,I am asking about the space between image and text.

Comment: set padding to your checkbox and then try android:padding="10dp"

Comment: See the thing is that in hdpi screen the space is showing automatically,and if I set padding,in xhdpi its working but in the hdpi the default space is trimming and if I set it to 20dp In xhdpi screen its spacing too large.